# database link in oracle 10g

Tags: sql, oracle10g

I have two users System and jagan in oracle10g . I could display contents of table TAB (select *from tab) when i login as system.But i want same result when i login as jagan also.. database name is XE. Can somebody give me syntax to create database link from jagan to XE.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Correct way to give users access to additional schemas in Oracle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/198952/correct-way-to-give-users-access-to-additional-schemas-in-oracle)

Comment: sounds like you're conflating 'user' (e.g. `jagan`) with 'database' (e.g. `XE`) - a database link is only useful when you have 2 databases.

Answer (score 1):

I do believe your question have been answered already:

[Correct way to give users access to additional schemas in Oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/198952/correct-way-to-give-users-access-to-additional-schemas-in-oracle)

Does that help?

Answer (score 0):

I am not at all familiar with Oracle but does "jagan" have read permissions/ownership over "XE" ?