# oracle 11g check user to view schema source code

Tags: oracle, permissions, schema

i am using oracle 11g and have 2 schema. is the way to grant the right to other users who can view the source code of these 2 schema beside sys/system and these schema users.

if can , how to check which user is able to view the source code of this schema?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Correct way to give users access to additional schemas in Oracle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/198952/correct-way-to-give-users-access-to-additional-schemas-in-oracle)

Answer (score 0):

This may be overkill, and feedback is welcome on the wisdom of doing this, but two options come to mind:

1. grant select on dba_source to otheruser;
2. grant select any dictionary to otheruser;

The first allows otheruser to select from DBA_SOURCE, where they will be able to find the source code from packages, procedures, and functions.

The second allows otheruser to select from any dictionary object, so they will also be able to see source for views.

The second part of your question, how to determine who can see it is very complicated, and dependent upon how you granted access.